# How to dynamically create refs react native video

Tags: react-native, ref

How can I create dynamic refs for a list of videos now that using just a string is not acceptable?

For example how to turn this into something dynamic

```
ref={(ref) => { this.player = ref }}
```

when you could just do this before

```
x = ['ref1', 'ref2']
ref={x[index]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it like this:-

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    ....
    this.myInput = [];
  }
...
render() {            // or return depending on your code
    for (i=0;i<=n;i++) {
        ... your code...   // i will go with TextInput for now
        <TextInput
            ref={(input) => {this.myInput[i]=input}}
            multiline={true}
            style={{ padding: 10, fontSize: 15 * myr, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'red' }}
            onChangeText={(text) => Email = text}
            placeholder="Email*"
        />
    }
}
```